# sum select rows based on condition tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I can't find an answer to this exact question.
Using tidyverse, I would like to sum the values of rows that contain a value >= 1 into a new row.
I have:

```
df <- tibble(dif = c(0, 1, 2, 3), n = c(2, 4, 6, 8))

    dif     n
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     2
2     1     4
3     2     6
4     3     8
```

In this case, rows 2:4 contain a value greater than 0. I would like to sum the `n` values of rows 2:4 into a new row, preferably retaining the `dif` value, giving an output like this.

```
    dif     n
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     2
2     1    18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group_by` whether `dif >= 1`; `+` coerces logical vectors (`TRUE`, `FALSE`) to `1` and `0`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(dif = +(dif >= 1)) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n))
```

output

```r
    dif     n
1     0     2
2     1    18
```

Comment: Nice! I was unaware of the `+` trick. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use a hack with `if_any()`, in an answer similar to @Maël 's:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(dif = if_any(dif)) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n))
```